# Getting Segmentation fault after installing torch on Debian 10

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pytorch, segmentation-fault, debian

Using pytorch's official [docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/), I installed torch on my Debian 10 server using this command as root:

```
 pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```

The installation seem to have done successuflly:

```
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, torch, pillow, numpy, torchvision, torchaudio
Successfully installed numpy-1.22.4 pillow-9.1.1 torch-1.11.0+cpu torchaudio-0.11.0+cpu torchvision-0.12.0+cpu typing-extensions-4.2.0
```

But When I try to import the library using `python3 -c 'import torch'` I get this error

> Segmentation fault

I'm wondering what could be wrong and how can I troubleshoot this problem?